# Python - Error importing class from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Can anyone guide on resolving the error ? The manager class method will need capability to create instance of User Class but it is not finding the module

Below is the folder structure and code and other details. **init**.py file is empty

```
Internal folder   
  ->main.py
  ->__init__.py
  ->User Folder
     -> user.py
     -> models.py
     -> usermanager.py
     -> __init__.py



ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
  at <module> (/home/vmagent/app/internal/user/usermanager.py:4)
  at <module> (/home/vmagent/app/main.py:2)
  at import_app (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py:352)
  at load_wsgiapp (/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py:52)
  at load (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py:65)
  at wsgi (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py:67)
  at load_wsgi (/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py:135)
  at init_process (/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py:126)
  at spawn_worker (/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:578)
```

main.py code

```
from internal.account import user,usermanager

def registerBlueprint(app, blueprint, manager):
     blueprint.manager = manager
     app.register_blueprint(blueprint)

registerBlueprint(app, user.request, usermanager)
```

user.py code

```
request = Blueprint('flex.user', __name__)

@request.route('/v1/user', methods=['POST'])
def CreateAccount():
   test = request.manager.UserManager()
   return test.CreateUser()
```

usermanager.py

```
from models import User

class UserManager:

   def __init__(self):
    pass

   def CreateUser(self):
      logger.log_text("AccountManger")
      data = json.dumps(dict(
        email="Hello@123.com",
        password="Test124"
       ))
       user = User(data)
       user.create()
       responseObject = dict(status='success', message='Successfully 
       registered.')
       return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 201
```

Comment: Is the indentation in the usermanger.py file correct?

Comment: you probably just need to include _ _ init _ _.py files in models and app folders (had to separate underscores, because comment removes them)

Comment: Out of curiosity, are the defs in `usermanager.py` not indented in your actual code?  If they're supposed to be methods of `UserManager`, then they should be indented.  I doubt this is what your problem is, but it jumped out at me so I figured I'd ask!

Comment: @LoremIpsum they are indented correctly in the file was just my mistake of copy/paste to stackoverflow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python paths can get kind of tricky.  I don't claim that this is the best approach, but it's what I hacked together on my lunch.  Perhaps it can get you where you need to go.

When you run `main.py`, you're in the `internal/` directory.  You need to go up a level and then access the `user/` directory.  That's what happens with `sys.path.append('../')`.  The module `usermanager.py` is in the `user/` directory, so to import from `user.py`, we want to point to the current directory.  Hence the period in `from .user import User`.

Here's the directory structure I used.  I believe it is the same as what you have.

```
C:.
├───internal
│       main.py
│       __init__.py
│
└───user
    │   models.py
    │   user.py
    │   usermanager.py
    └───__init__.py
```

### __init__.py

The `__init__.py` files are empty.   Their presence indicates to Python that the directories are modules<sup>1</sup>.

### main.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')

from user import user
from user import usermanager
from user import models

my_user = user.User()
my_user.message()

my_user_manager = usermanager.UserManager()
my_user_manager.message()
my_user_manager.CreateUser()

my_model = models.Model()
my_model.message()
```

### models.py

```
class Model():

    def message(self):
        print("This is a Model!")
```

### user.py

```
class User():

    def message(self):
        print("This is a User!")
```

### usermanager.py

```
from .user import User

class UserManager():
    
    def message(self):
        print("This is a UserManager!")

    def CreateUser(self):
        new_user = User()
        print("I created the user: ", new_user)
```

---

Now, when I call `main.py` I get:

```
c:\project\internal>python main.py
This is a User!
This is a UserManager!
I created the user:  <user.user.User object at 0x0000000002A61EB8>
This is a Model!
```

Everyone is talking to everyone else.  Hopefully you can extrapolate that to your use case! If not, Chris Yeh has an article "[The Definitive Guide to Python import Statements](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html)" you may find helpful.

---

<sup>1</sup>  See [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) to learn more about how that works.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `models` module in the standard library, and you do not have a file named `models.py` listed here, so python cannot find it.  If `models.py` is in some subdirectory, that subdirectory needs to be [in your python path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder), and you need to be sure that they contain an `__init__.py` file.  That is the meaning of the error you're encountering here.

Comment: @morris  I have added the folder structure for more clarity

Comment: Two follow-up questions: do you have an `__init__.py` file in this folder (if so, what are its contents?), and where is `main.py` in relation to this folder?

Comment: updated in the description. yes init file is there and is empty at root and sub directory level